# Calculating current year and previous year and inserting it into a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data range in a table from '2014-06-01' to '2016-06-01'. How to show the values for current date and previous date in a table.

Example: the value for the date '2015-01-01'(current year date) is 100 and in '2014-01-01'(previous year date) is 200.

So the table values should be

```
Row1. Date -2015-01-01, PreviousYear-200,CurrentYear-100
Row2. Date -2015-02-01
...
upto..
RowN. Date -2016-01-01
```

Please help.

Comment: what have you tried so far? to be honest this is not difficult

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I don't want to pass any parameters like date, I have tried with while loop, where I take start date as current date, pass that date in the query and fetch that particular date data and insert it to the table, after inserting i'm incriminating the  current date. But the problem is I'm getting duplicates for each day.

Answer (score 0):

Use the year function to display year of your date ie.

```
YEAR(GETDATE())
```

Then use dateadd to get previous year

```
DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE())
```

Also it would help a ton if you provided some of your code, and what you've tried.